# How to run Docker for Mac without TLS?

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

How can I `unset DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` when using Docker for Mac. I want to disable TLS for the docker engine but I cant find a config file or how to boot `dockerd` manually.